# How to map many dates to a booking in hibernate and avoid redundancies?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, database-design

Lets just say that a booking can have many dates! I think my code is a bit redundant as I'm having to insert a ***booking_date*** into a ***booking*** AND a ***booking*** into a ***booking_date***.

Take the following structure, a booking can have 1 or many dates attached to it (in this case, to you it may not make much sense.)

#### Booking_date:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="booking_date")
public class BookingDate {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="booking_date_id")
private int id;

@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
@Column(name="start_date")
private Date startDate;

@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
@Column(name="end_date" )
private Date endDate;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "booking_id")
private Booking booking;
```

#### Booking:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="booking")
public class Booking {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="booking_id")
private int bookingId;

// One booking to one booking date...
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "booking")
private BookingDate bookingDate;
```

I think I'm doing something wrong here, as when I go to insert a booking into the database I'd have to insert the booking into the booking_date & visa versa.

Lets take the following example out of my code...Inserting a booking with multiple dates.

```
@RequestMapping(value="create/booking", method=RequestMethod.POST,  produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
    Booking bookingCreate(@RequestBody BookingContext bookingcont, BindingResult bindingResult) {

 Booking booking = new Booking();
```

I've created the booking entity, now I need to insert a bunch of dates to that booking. First I have to loop through the `List` of `BookingDate`'s and set the booking we created above to each of them (I feel this can be avoided)?

```
List<BookingDate> bookingDates = <Pretend this is a list of BookingDate objects>
// Loop through bookingdates and assign the booking obj to each of them
for (BookingDate bookingDate : bookingDates) {
   bookingDate.setBookingDate(bookingDate);
}
```

I would then go and assign the bookingDates object to our booking object:

```
booking.setBookingDate(bookingDates); // Insert multiple booking dates for the booking
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how it should be

```
Booking booking = new Booking();
//setting data in booking
List<BookingDate> bookingDates = <Pretend this is a list of BookingDate objects>
booking.setBookingDate(bookingDates);
session.save(booking);
```

The reason this should work is because there is `Cascade.ALL` on booking hence saving `booking` should save the associated `bookingdate`

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "booking")
private BookingDate bookingDate;
```

Also you dont need to set `booking` in each `bookingdate` as the cascade is from `booking` not from `bookingdate` hence the `booking` needs to know that there exists a list of `bookingdate` not vice versa.
Hope this helps